# iOS 8 Photos framework: Get a specific list of albums

Tags: ios, objective-c, phasset

I am trying to get all get all photos by except for the photos in my own album.
I try to get all the photos using the method in this answer.
[ios - Simple example to get list of photo albums?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21131175/ios-simple-example-to-get-list-of-photo-albums)
but I can't find an option to filtrate my own album.

I use the code like below...I can get the the albums except my own one,but how can I get PHFetchResult with all the photos except my the photos in my own album?

Thank you.

```
PHFetchOptions *albumsFetchOption = [[PHFetchOptions alloc]init];
NSString *string = @"MyCam";
albumsFetchOption.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title != %@",string];

PHFetchResult *userAlbums = [PHAssetCollection fetchAssetCollectionsWithType:PHAssetCollectionTypeAlbum subtype:PHAssetCollectionSubtypeAny options:albumsFetchOption];
```

Answer (score 3):

At last ,I use NSArray instead of  PHFetchResult...

//fetch all

```
PHFetchOptions *allPhotosfetchOption = [[PHFetchOptions alloc]init];
allPhotosfetchOption.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:NO]];
allPhotosfetchOption.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"mediaType == 1"];

__block NSMutableArray *allAssetArray = [NSMutableArray new];
PHFetchResult *result = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithMediaType:PHAssetMediaTypeImage options:allPhotosfetchOption];
[result enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(PHAsset *asset, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        [allAssetArray addObject:asset];
}];

//MyCam Album 
NSString *string = @"MyCam";
PHFetchOptions *albumFetchOption = [[PHFetchOptions alloc]init];
albumFetchOption.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title == %@",string];
PHFetchResult *albumResult = [PHAssetCollection fetchAssetCollectionsWithType:PHAssetCollectionTypeAlbum subtype:PHAssetCollectionSubtypeAlbumRegular options:albumFetchOption];

[albumResult enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(PHAssetCollection *collection, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    PHFetchResult *loftAssetResult = [PHAsset fetchAssetsInAssetCollection:collection options:nil];
    [loftAssetResult enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(PHAsset *asset, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
                if ([allAssetArray containsObject:asset]) {
                    [allAssetArray removeObject:asset];
                }
    }];
}];
```