# Access default photo gallery from Android and IOS and display in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

It is possible to access default photo gallery from Android and IOS and display in Xamarin.Forms

Note: I am not talk about picker. I need list of photos from gallery and show in list in Portable Library in xamarin forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no out of the box API available in the Xamarin Forms to enumerate the images from the iOS/Android. You will need to create `CustomRenderer` or `DependencyService` to list the images.

The following post may help you implement it -

- iOS https://stackoverflow.com/a/32863564/85606
- Android https://stackoverflow.com/a/4196411/85606

Answer (score 0):

The below link is about creating your own gallery, where you can use it as per your requirement..
"http://rasmustc.com/blog/Image-Gallery-With-Xamarin-Forms/"...
Hope this helps...